# Can I quit an already started Marie Curie Postdoctoral fellowship to start an assistant professorship?

Tags: funding, quitting, assistant-professor, covid-19

I received a Marie Curie Individual Fellowship in Europe. Now, due to the institute's lack of equipment + COVID, it seems I will be able to do barely any of the things I had planned. I have been offered a position as Assistant Professor at an Asian International University of Technology.

Would you leave a European fellowship for a tenure track assistant professorship that has a 2+2 year structure?

What happens if you quit a fellowship for an assistant professorship?

Comment: What would a good answer address? Yes, you can do that. Whether it is a good idea really depends on the conditions of the assistant professorship (teaching load, possibility to get tenured, funding, ...).  No, nothing bad happens when you quit the fellowship; at most the people at the host institution might be disappointed (or mad, in case you openly lied to them), but they'll understand eventually.